# Deleted tax rules still present on products

Tags: magento-1.9, tax

I recently realized that all my tax rules were created 6 times with the exact same name and settings. I have deleted all the duplicates, but for some reason the old rules can still be chosen when editing tax rules per product.

How do I make them disappear completely?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you removed the tax rules under `Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Rules` but didn't remove the `Sales > Tax > Product Tax Classes` which are shown when editing a product

Comment: You are absolute right. Thank you very much! How do I know which product tax classes represents which tax rules? They seem to contain nothing but a name when editing them...

Comment: Correct. and they don't do that much anyway. You have to map them to a tax rule for them to have effect

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. Damn, TAX in magento is confusing...